# HDF5 bad performance for tables with non-numerical columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text, hdf5

I have pulled some big tables (typically 100M rows X 100 columns) from a database, with both numerical and textual columns. Now I need to save them to a remote machine which doesn't allow for setting up databases. After the data are saved there, the use case would be occasional reads of these files by different collaborators and in-place queries are favorable.

So I figured that HDF5 would be the file format to use. However, the performance seems really bad, both read and write, even worse than .csv files. I used a random subset (1M rows) of a big table to test the saving process in Python. Some info about this test dataframe:

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 1 to 1000000
Data columns (total 49 columns):
 #   Column                  Non-Null Count    Dtype
---  ------                  --------------    -----
 0   xid                     1000000 non-null  int64
 1   yid                     1000000 non-null  int64
 2   timestamp               1000000 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 ...
 7   content1                361892  non-null  object
 8   content2                168397  non-null  object
 ...
dtypes: datetime64[ns](14), float64(14), int64(5), object(16)
memory usage: 381.5+ MB

>>> df['content2'].str.len().describe()
count    168397.000000
mean        111.846975
std         427.148959
min           4.000000
25%          72.000000
50%          73.000000
75%          73.000000
max       13320.000000
```

I allocated 128G memory for this process. And when I saved this DF:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False), number=5)
157.54342390294187

>>> store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
>>> timeit(lambda: store.put(key='df', value=df, append=False, index=False, complevel=9, complib='blosc:zstd', format='table',min_itemsize={'content2': 65535, 'content2': 65535}}), number=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1030, in put
    self._write_to_group(
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1697, in _write_to_group
    s.write(
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 4137, in write
    table = self._create_axes(
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3806, in _create_axes
    data_converted = _maybe_convert_for_string_atom(
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 4812, in _maybe_convert_for_string_atom
    data_converted = _convert_string_array(data, encoding, errors).reshape(data.shape)
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 4857, in _convert_string_array
    data = np.asarray(data, dtype=f"S{itemsize}")
  File "/opt/apps/anaconda/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 61.0 GiB for an array with shape (1, 1000000) and data type |S65535
```

Even if I used smaller subsets (like 100K) that didn't lead to this `MemoryError`, saving to HDF5 is significantly slower than `to_csv`. This seems surprising to me given the touted advantages of HDF5 when handling large datasets. Is it because HDF5 is still bad for handling text data? Note that the textual columns do have long-tail distributions and the content can be as long as 60K characters (which is why I set `min_itemsize` to 65535).

I would appreciate any suggestion on the most appropriate file format to use, if not HDF5, or any fixes to my current approach. Thanks!

Comment: First, HDF5 can handle large amounts of data. That's why it was created. NASA stores TB and PB of data with HDF5 (not all in 1 file). Your string data is very large. Each value consumes 65535 bytes. Multiply by 1M rows and you get the 61 GiB required for that value only. And you have a lot more data: 5 ints at 4 bytes each, 14 floats at 8 bytes, plus14 datetimes and 16 objects. Likely you will have to save in smaller increments. Processing time on a remote machine also includes local-server data transfer time, which may or may not be a bottleneck. Test I/O performance locally first.

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks. The test was done in the Python environment on remote server, *after* the data was loaded there, so the time reports didn't include local-server data transfer time. My main confusion is why .csv wouldn't cause the memory error and actually performed much better than HDF when saving the same data.